# How to run a program from terminal input(linux)?

Tags: c, linux

While I think I have the grasp on how `fork()`, `exec()`, `wait()` and `pid` work in C, I have yet to find a way how to run a personal program from within a program.

Here's my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h> /* for fork() */
#include<sys/types.h> /* for pid_t */
#include<sys/wait.h> /* fpr wait() */

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char  fileName[255];
    pid_t pid;

    switch (pid = fork()) {
    case -1: //Did not fork properly
        perror("fork");
        break;

    case 0: //child
        execv(fileName[0],fileName);

        puts("Oh my. If this prints, execv() must have failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        break;
    default: //parent
        //Infinite Loop
        while (1) {
            printf(" %s > ", argv[0]);
            scanf("%s", fileName); // gets filename
            if (fileName[0] == '\0') continue;
            printf("\n Entered file: %s",fileName); // prints the fileName
            waitpid(pid,0,0); /* wait for child to exit() */
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

My questions are the following:

1. I want to take a string as an input and I want to limit its scope to 255 characters. Is `char fileName[255]` and then `scanf("%s", fileName);` the way to go? Should I use `getLine()` or some other function instead?
2. Let's say that the input is taken correctly. How do I execute say an existing  hello world program. Will the input be stored in `*argv[]` ? I found out that in a different program I could use

   ```
   static char *argv[] = { "echo", "Foo is my name." , NULL };
   execv("/bin/echo", argv);
   ```

   in order to echo "Foo is my name.". Can I do something similar with a helloWorld program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing a single character as the command name, and the name string as the start of a list of arguments — as if the prototype for `execv()` were <s>`int execv(char cmd, char *args)`</s>.

The actual prototype is: `int execv(char *cmd, char **args)`, so you need:

```
char *args[2] = { fileName, 0 };

execv(args[0], args);
```

I assume you set `fileName` to a meaningful value somewhere — that isn't shown.  For example, it might be `"./local_program"`.  It will be treated as the pathname of the executable.

If you want to read the name, then you can use `fgets()` or `getline()`, but you'll need to remove the newline:

```
if (fgets(fileName, sizeof(fileName), stdin) != 0)
{
    fileName[strcspn(fileName, "\n")] = '\0';
    …as before…
}
```

or:

```
char *fileName = 0;
size_t length = 0;
if (getline(&fileName, &length, stdin) != -1)  /* Not EOF! */
{
    fileName[strcspn(fileName, "\n")] = '\0';
    …as before…
}
free(fileName);
```

The use of `strcspn()` avoids having to special case overly long command lines such that there isn't a newline in the `fileName`.  Note that this does not attempt to split the input line into a command name and arguments at spaces or anything fancy like that.  That's the next level of shell implementation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    char fileName[256];
    if (fgets(fileName, sizeof(fileName), stdin) != 0)
    {
        fileName[strcspn(fileName, "\n")] = '\0';
        char *args[129];
        char **argv = args;
        char *cmd = fileName;
        const char *whisp = " \t\f\r\b\n";
        /* Ugh — strtok()?  OK while only handling white space separators */
        char *token;
        while ((token = strtok(cmd, whisp)) != 0)
        {
            *argv++ = token;
            cmd = 0;
        }
        *argv = 0;

        execv(args[0], args);
        fprintf(stderr, "Oops!\n");
    }
    return 1;
}
```

I don't need to check for overflow of the `args` array because 256 characters of input, minus terminating null, cannot be split to produce more than 128 single-character arguments, each separated from the adjacent ones by a single white space character.  Using `strtok()` is a temporary band-aid.  As soon as you need to deal with real shell syntax (pipes, I/O redirections, quoted strings with spaces, etc), `strtok()` is woefully the wrong tool.  (It — [`strtok()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtok.html) — is also the wrong function to use in any library function whatsoever.  Use POSIX [`strtok_r()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtok_r.html) on Unix or Microsoft's [`strtok_s()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ftsafwz3.aspx) on Windows if you must use a `strtok()`-like function in library code.)

Comment: Thank you for your quick and thorough answer. The only part of your question that I couldn't understand completely was the assumption that I set fileName to a value. Do you mean initialization? In that case, I haven't . Do I need to? In my mind when the program ran, it would prompt the user and the user would type something like "./helloWorld" or "/bin/./helloWorld". And this would be the value of fileName.

Comment: The typing in of the name is what I meant by 'setting `fileName` to a value'.  As written, you were using an uninitialized character string as a command, which is unlikely to work well.  As long as you set `fileName` to something faintly appropriate somehow, you should be OK.  Both `./helloWorld` and `/bin/./helloWorld` would work, though the `./` is not needed (`execv()` is unaffected by `$PATH`, and if you specify just `helloWorld`, it will be treated the same as `./helloWorld`).  The `/bin/./helloWorld` is iffy; the `/./` could be just `/` and you should not be putting software in `/bin`.

Answer (score 0):

As it stands, you'll need to fix the compilation errors from your code:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -g -Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings     36501711.cpp   -o 36501711
36501711.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
36501711.cpp:18:25: error: invalid conversion from ‘char’ to ‘const char*’ [-fpermissive]
         execv(fileName[0],fileName);
                         ^
36501711.cpp:18:35: error: cannot convert ‘char*’ to ‘char* const*’ for argument ‘2’ to ‘int execv(const char*, char* const*)’
         execv(fileName[0],fileName);
                                   ^
36501711.cpp: At global scope:
36501711.cpp:7:5: warning: unused parameter ‘argc’ [-Wunused-parameter]
 int main(int argc, char* argv[])
     ^
```

The warning (about unused `argc`) is harmless, but the errors are real, and need to be fixed.

You need to initialise `fileName` *before* you fork, otherwise the child won't have any valid data there:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h> /* for fork() */
#include<sys/types.h> /* for pid_t */
#include<sys/wait.h> /* fpr wait() */

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char  fileName[255];
    pid_t pid;

    //Infinite Loop
    while (1) {
        printf(" %s > ", argv[0]);
        scanf("%s", fileName);
        if (fileName[0] == '\0')
            break;
        printf("\n Entered file: %s\n", fileName);

        pid = fork();
        switch (pid) {
        case -1: //Did not fork properly
            perror("fork");
            break;

        case 0: //child
            execl(fileName, fileName, 0);
            perror("exec");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            break;

        default: //parent
            waitpid(pid,0,0); /* wait for child to exit() */
            break;
        }
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```